# Flash shared object always gets reset

Tags: string, actionscript-3, flash, shared, shared-objects

So in my game, you want to make the potato as big as possible. The first time you play it, the highscores work fine,giving you a highscore and saving it. The problem is that whenever you play the game, the highscore is always reset to your current score, which means that even if you get a lower score then your previous highscore, it saves your current score as the highscore. my code looks like this:

```
var savedstuff:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myStuff");

if (savedstuff.data.bestScore = 0) {
     savedstuff.data.bestScore = 1
}


bigness.text = finish.toString();

if (finish > savedstuff.data.bestScore){
    savedstuff.data.bestScore = finish;
}
best.text = savedstuff.data.bestScore.toString();
savedstuff.flush();
```

where bigness is a textbox displaying your current score, best is a textbox displaying your highscore and bestScore is where the best score is stored. I have the line "if (finish > savedstuff.dada.bestScore)" which should make the overwrite only occur if you get a higher score, but it seems to just ignore that line. my game is here
http://www.kongregate.com/games/pwnedcat/grow-a-potato

any help is appreciated. I just started flash so I really don't know anything. :(

Comment: I'd check to see if "savedstuff.data.bestScore" is a string and if it is then parse it back to a number before comparing. Then try tracing out both of the parts in the if statement as well the output of that comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the condition, it should be

```
savedstuff.data.bestScore == 0
```

Instead of

```
savedstuff.data.bestScore = 0
```